# SharePoint - how to prevent particular users from accessing a site

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I have two different sites - `site A` and `site B`.

I have provided access to all users to `site A`.

How can I manage the permissions such that a sub-group of users (in an active directory DL) will have access to only `site B`, and not `site A`?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood the problem correctly but this kind of permission to sites you can always resolve by:

1) split users in AD into two separate groups and then in site A add to some SP group (like visitors or members) one AD group and to site B the other one. Do not use all users.

2) you could share the site by adding directly user in the SP groups. For example You could developer a simple powershell script and with it you would determine which user should be able to visit which site and the add the login (user profile) of this user to the correct site. This script could be scheduled in schedule task form maintenance.

3) you could configure a custom claim provider and based on some permissions from AD you could generate some claims for users and then add this generated claim to site A and different claim to site B. The user which with the correct claim will be able to enter the proper site. Please check [here](https://www.slideshare.net/mobile/AntonioMaio2/developing-custom-claim-providers-to-enable-authorization-in-share-point-antonio-maio-published) for more details about this option

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint doesn't have a `Deny` option.

So finally I setup the new site with access only to the concerned DL.

In the original site, I added some code in the masterpage to redirect the users in the DL to the new site as soon as any page is opened. This is working fine now.